# Conversão de uma consulta LINQ em métodos

Tags: c#, sql, linq

A seguinte consulta em LINQ (com query) abaixo é usada para listar todos os fornecedores que tem uma conta (relacionamento 1 para 1):

```
from f in fornecedores
join c in contas on f.ID equals c.FornecedorID
select f
```

Como posso atingir o mesmo resultado usando métodos LINQ com `.Select() ...` ?

Comment: Por que acha que não é bom assim?

Comment: Pra mim parece OK também, se a consulta não estivesse funcionando seria outro papo. :)

Comment: A primeira _query_ é bem melhor que a 2ª. Porque quer trocar uma por outra?

Comment: Na verdade queria saber como ela ficaria em métodos (mesmo na prática sendo o mesmo resultado). Vou editar a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para se usar o Join, é muito melhor utilizar a sintaxe em vez dos métodos, visto que o método Join() possui {4,5} parâmetros, o que torna a leitura mais difícil.

Ainda assim, respondendo a sua pergunta, sua consulta ficaria:

`fornecedores.Join(contas, f => f.ID, c => c.FornecedorID, (f, c) => f);`

Parâmetros:

1º: Coleção a qual você fará Join

2º: Chave da primeira coleção

3º: Chave da segunda coleção

4º: Função que retorna o item do resultado, é quase o mesmo que utilizar o Select(), porém recebe dois parâmetros, o primeiro é o item da primeira coleção (fornecedores), o segundo é o item da segunda coleção (contas).